# Facebook/Graph API in iOS: Create Groups and Manage users through our app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-game-groups

It seems that Graph API only supports Group Creation and Management for game app that are in the App Center.

However, we would like to integrate Facebook Groups into our iOS application(not a game app) and need the ability to create new groups and manage users through our app. Is there a way to do this through the Facebook/Graph API or is another approach we could leverage to develop an integrated solution?

Problem Description: We're developing an iOS app where one of the user(Role base) can create Groups and manage the group.

```
•   Admin user Register/Log in to Facebook via the app
•   Admin user creates a group
•   Admin user can add people to the group
•   Admin user creates an event for the group.
•   Admin user can invite members to an event.
•   Eventually, Admin user will be managing the group using the app.
```

If more info needed feel free to drop a mail.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/app-game-groups/#create_group
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/

It looks like the only way to create a group is through a game -- separate applications don't have that permission or the capabilities (for now?).

Answer (score 0):

The App Center requirement should be removed and work for you.